# How to handle tile rotation in pytmx?

Tags: python, pygame, tmx, pytmx

I am loading a map from Tiled with pytmx, but when i draw the tiles, they aren't rotated like in the editor.

The code i'm using to draw the map is this:

```py
tiled_map = pytmx.util_pygame.load_pygame(f"mymap.tmx")
tile_list = []
tile_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
tile_layer = tiled_map.get_layer_by_name("tiles")
for x, y, image in tile_layer.tiles():
    tile = Tile(x*self.tiled_map.tilewidth, y*self.tiled_map.tileheight, image=image)
    tile_group.add(tile)
    tilelist.append(tile)

#later in the code
for tile in tile_list:
    sur.blit(tile.image, (tile.x, tile.y))
```

The tiles all get drawn out in the correct place, but they all have the default rotation, even though they are rotated in Tiled:
[image: in tiled]
[image: In pygame]

I know this question is similar to [How to correctly display rotation object with pytmx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817307/how-to-correctly-display-rotation-object-with-pytmx), but it did not help me as my problem is with tiles and not objects.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a .tmx file to export the map?
save the map as CSV, CSV is more accessible a lot than .tmx
.tmx is used to save and load it in Tiled not used in rendering the Map

That is what I use

```
Map = open("*map file location*", 'r')

Read = csv.reader(Mapv)

for row in Read:
    Tile.append(row)
```

and put this in the while loop

```
for y in range(8):
    for x in range(60):
         if Tile[y][x] == '*the_tile_number*':
              Screen.blit(*block_surface*, (x*60,y*60))
```